# Unable to copy backslash from PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I am unable to copy backslash from PhpStorm, it's working fine if I copy from Windows/Notepad/browser etc.

For example, I have a code in my PhpStorm that looks like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

and when I paste that code it looks like this:

```php
use IlluminateSupportFacadesStorage;
```

Somehow I am unable to copy backslashes from the code, they are not event appearing in the Windows clipboard.

Is there any kind of setting that gets accidentally disabled and needs to enable?
It was working fine a few seconds ago but I don't know what happened.

Comment: 1) Could be some weird glitch. Try restarting your PC. 2) If nothing -- disable all custom (not bundled by default) plugins and restart the IDE.

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne for your response I disable a few plugins that just accidentally get enabled and were creating issues with the copy feature of the IDE.
Have a nice day